# "a matrix is positive semi-definite" not necessarily equavalent to "all leading principle minors are nonegative"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Have a look at this matrix:
$$
H = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{array}} \right).$$
All the leading principle minors of $H$ are nonegative.
However, $H$ is an indefinite matrix, since $H$'s eigenvalues are $-1,-1,1,1$.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is true is that a symmetric matrix is positive *definite* if all its principal minors are positive. In order to convert that to a criterion for positive semi-definiteness, add a small $\epsilon$ to the diagonal:
$$ H+\epsilon = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon&0&1&0 \\ 0&\epsilon&0&1 \\ 1&0&\epsilon&0 \\ 0&1&0&\epsilon \end{pmatrix}. $$
The principal minors are
$$ \epsilon, \epsilon^2, -\epsilon + \epsilon^3, 1-2\epsilon^2+\epsilon^4. $$
As you can see, for small $\epsilon>0$ the third minor is negative. In fact, we can come up with a criterion for when a minor is positive for small $\epsilon$: its leading coefficient (smallest power of $\epsilon$) has to be positive. If this is true for all minors, then the matrix is positive semidefinite.